# Approximation of an integral when function varies little

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, approximation

I am doing a circuit analysis and getting this approximation below. I don't know if it is correct or not. I can check it for several cases but I think there is a formal proof of this.

Can anyone prove or show me how to prove this or even reject this?

> $$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx  ≈ f(x)*(b-a) $$ where f(x) varies little over
>    the range [a, b].

**Update:**

After reading AntonioVargas comment, I reviewed the integral and actually the upper and lower limit are functions of x.

I will provide more context. I am studying the lecture [here](http://ecee.colorado.edu/copec/book/slides/Ch7slide.pdf) and at page 18, I think there is an approximation. Note that Vg(t) (the dotted line) is not a constant but a function of t.

[image]

Comment: It would probably be best to start by making the concept that $f(x)$ varying slightly on $[a,b]$ a little more formal. Possibly just $f(x) - \epsilon_1 \leq f(x) \leq f(x) + \epsilon_2$ for $x \in [a,b]$. 

Then you can start bounding the integral.

Comment: The left-hand side doesn't depend on $x$ bur the right-hand side does. Perhaps you mean something like $\approx f(a)(b-a)$ instead?

Comment: @AntonioVargas: I mean f(x) not f(a). I read this lecture, page 18 and I assume that they make that approximation because <Vg(t)> is not a constant. 
http://ecee.colorado.edu/copec/book/slides/Ch7slide.pdf

Comment: @AntonioVargas: you are right about integral limits. Actually the limits here are function of x as in the lecture above. I will update it.